# Can't close bootstrap modal via data-attribute data-backdrop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to **close** my **modal with a click on background**. For this I want to **use** data-attribute **data-backdrop**, like this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <a class="link">
                <img src="URL" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where is a problem?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Because you have to use `data-backdrop="true"`*

**See this bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/kDYLtTapC4

**HTML** :

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true">   // <----- HERE
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `backdrop` defaults to true, so you could just leave out `data-backdrop` altogether.