# bootstrap modal show close when clicked outside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap modal like this :

```
  <div class="modal show" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-keyboard="true" data-backdrop="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

It gives me a good modal.

Here I used `show` to initialize modal at first. Now when my modal is initialized and I click outside the modal it does not close.

What might be the issue here

Answer (score 0):

`data-backdrop="static"`  this property with value 'static' will prevent closing the modal.

`data-keyboard="false"` this property prevent closing the modal by pressing Esc.

Comment: I guesss I am asking how to close it.. It will give static I know that

Comment: If you want it to close on click outside, do not use data-backdrop="static"  property

Comment: If you see in my question I am using data-backdrop="true"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251455/cant-close-bootstrap-modal-via-data-attribute-data-backdrop

Comment: I dont know if you are getting me or not.. I am using `modal show` class.. and data-backdrop is not working thats all

Answer (score 0):

Use with proper bootstrap classes its work now,

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19519/][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19519/
```

Thanks

Comment: You are not getting my point.. I am not using `moda fade` I am using modal `show` ..